# How to break up a signal into equal blocks based on a threshold

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have a signal which is saved as a csv file. I'm trying to break up the signal into individual blocks of a fixed length (say 100 samples) for analysis (fft, wavelet, amplitude etc) when a threshold is crossed. If the threshold was to be placed at 5, I still need a bit before the threshold included in the block (say 30 of the 100 samples before the major peak, 70 after). How would I go about this, only getting 1 block output per signal pulse?
Many thanks in advance!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BicFJ.jpg)

I've tried looping through the array to find data points where they're above the threshold but I'm struggling to reduce it to one point per pulse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your signal is in `x`, the following would find the index of the first peak that crosses the threshold.

```
threshold = 5;
n_pre = 30;
n_post = 70;

ind_first_peak = find(x > threshold, 1, 'first');
ind_pre = ind_first_peak - n_pre
ind_end = ind_first_peak + n_post;

ind_selection = ind_start:ind_end;
x_selection = x(ind_selection);
```

Now we can remove the first peak from the original signal, and repeat:

```
x_new = x;
x_new(x_selection) = []; % remove the first peak, so x_new can be used by find again.
```

This is not very robust, but depending on your signal and threshold could work. If you have access to the Signal Processing Toolbox, you could check [`findpeaks`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html).

Comment: Thanks for that! I think that should work for my signal given it's pretty low noise after wavelet noise reduction. I'll have a look at the signal processing toolbox too. Cheers!